# What docker storage driver is good for "production" use?

Tags: filesystems, docker

I have "growing disk space" issues with VFS driver. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/3925) VFS is not used in production. May be you know what driver should I use in "production" environment?

Comment: I asked a related question: why is the vfs storage backend not considered suitable for production: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736778/why-is-the-docker-vfs-storage-backend-not-considered-suitable-for-production

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this question is still actual for me. Is `btrfs` driver good for production? Are there some other drivers?

Comment: @zergood if you run ``mkfs.btrfs`` you read: ``WARNING! - Btrfs v3.12 IS EXPERIMENTAL
WARNING! - see http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org before using
`` on a stable Ubuntu 14.04. May that answer your question?