# running docker remotely on openvz

Tags: docker, kvm, openvz

I have a openvz vps which is centos 7 but with a 2.6 kernel. I know this is not compatible with docker. I have another KVM vps which has docker on it. Is there anyway to access docker in KVM remotely using my openvz vps? Basically I want my openvz box to be my dev machine and Ill deploy to KVM docker. What would be an ideal setup above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the host has a 2.6.x kernel, but that covers a couple different releases.  I have made docker work in an openvz VPS on a host with 2.6.32 kernel (derived from RedHat el6) but it would probably not work for kernels 2.6.18 or 2.6.9 (you really should upgrade if you have 2.6.9 as that is based on RedHat el4 kernel, 2.6.18 should be fine until 3/2017).  You can find instructions to make it work with a compatible kernel at the [openvz wiki](https://openvz.org/Docker_inside_CT).  WARNING: docker does not perform very well in this configuration (2.6.32 kernel, CentOS 7 VPS) as you do not get any of the fancy filesystem layering functionality since you are forced to use the ["vfs" storage engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736778/why-is-the-docker-vfs-storage-backend-not-considered-suitable-for-production).  Each layer of the docker container will be a full copy of its underlying filesystem, grossly ballooning disk usage for images with lots of layers.

If you are not running a docker compatible kernel, you would not be able to run any of the docker tools at all, so your options are limited.  If you still want to develop docker containers on your VPS to move to your KVM, you could use chroot and yum/rpm to construct your container and make a [${docker_image}.tgz file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/#/create-a-full-image-using-tar) on your VPS and then copy that to your KVM and import into docker.

Hope that helps.