# Virtualize my VPS

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, vps

I spent 2 full days to try to install a virtualization solution on my VPS in order to deploy a container or a virtualized OS (linux).

Why ? because I want to "one-click" export or recreate all the content of my VPS on my own local server (nginx / apache / discourse / databases etc... many customizations).

My VPS is : Openvz, 8 GB, SSD 40 GB - tun OK, overlay : KO - kernel 2.6.32-042stab120.6 . Os available : Centos, Fedora, Ubuntu

As you know, the kernel is emulated, so it's quiet better than 2.6 but, no possibility to upgrade because it's on host.

I tried everything :

- install qemu (+virt-install) and create a virtual machine --> ko
- install virtualbox and create a virtual machine --> ko
- install docker --> KO (kernel 3.0 required)
- install rocket --> not supported
- install vagrant --> useless because virtualbox is needed

I have looked for many solutions, even older ones but none worked :(
My last idea is to fake the linux kernel to start docker daemon...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working inside an OpenVZ container, you will not be able to get qemu or virtualbox running due to not having the kvm kernel modules inside your VPS.

Docker should work though, I have had success getting it working in the past following the instructions [here](https://openvz.org/Docker_inside_CT).  I have only done the steps for CentOS 7 VPS but it appears it should work for Debian as well.  It may require some assistance from your provider if your VPS does not have a bridged interface and the "full" netfilter option.

There are some performance issues with this setup though.  You are limited to using the [Docker "vfs" storage engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736778/why-is-the-docker-vfs-storage-backend-not-considered-suitable-for-production) which eliminates the fancy Docker storage layers and makes the Docker images much larger (each layer is a full copy of the underlying filesystem).

This setup should work for your use case, you would be able to use the docker tools to build/run/pull/import/export Docker images using your VPS.  Just remember to keep an eye on how large your layers get so you do not run yourself out of disk space.